# Resetting the value of a select after a choice has been selected

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, frontend, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a select in an  in blazor. The first option is a simple "Choose..." string, and the rest are the options from a list. When you pick an option it removes the option from the select, and adds it to another list underneath. You can also remove an option from the list underneath and it goes back to the select options. Everything works the way I want to, I got the logic of moving items back and forth without issues. However, it doesn't always reset the select value back to "Choose.." instead it sometimes picks just the next value in the list.

Here is my code for the select

```
<select class="select" value="@appId" @onchange="PickApplication">
    <option selected value="">Applications</option>
    @foreach (var app in model.Applications.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationId))
    {
        <option value="@app.ApplicationId.ToString()">@app.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

And the PickApplication code.

```
private void PickApplication(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
       // early return
        if (e.Value is null || e.Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            return;
        }

        
        appId = "";

        // remove the application from the displayed list, and put it in the picked list
        int id = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString()!);

        var app = vm.Applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicationId == id);
        ChosenApplications.Add(app);
        vm.Applications.Remove(app);
}
```

As I mentioned, the moving of app between the two lists works as intended, it's the resetting of the value back to always being "Choose..." that doesn't work, everytime it works sometimes§.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `@bind:get`/`@bind:set` modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-bindgetbindset-modifiers-and-avoid-event-handlers-for-two-way-data-binding):

```
<select class="select" @bind:get="@appId" @bind:set="PickApplication">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    @foreach (var app in model.Applications.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationId))
    {
        <option value="@app.ApplicationId.ToString()">@app.Name</option>
    }
</select>


@code {
    private void PickApplication(string? value)
    {
       // early return
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        // remove the application from the displayed list, and put it in the picked list
        int id = int.Parse(value!);

        var app = vm.Applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicationId == id);
        ChosenApplications.Add(app);
        vm.Applications.Remove(app);
    }
}
```